Efficient Block Processing
I want to process all blocks and parse transactions/instructions. Currently I use Quicknode as an RPC provider, getBlocks + batched getBlock for data loading, typescript for coding and AWS single-core machine for hosting.

Are there any better (more compact / with filtering of transactions by mentioned accounts) ways to retrieve data from blockchain? (blockSubscribe is not stable in a way that the connection may drop any time)

I don't really like Typescript and it's probably less efficient than Rust/Go (in this situation it actually affects the costs of hosting). But the problem is the lack of libraries: I need to parse IDLs. What languge / libraries would you recommend?

My AWS machine falls behind the blockchain pretty fast and I think it can be solved by splitting the load across cores (which can be done using worker_threads). If you had the same or similar experience please share what hosting service you went with and how much it cost.



You may prefer using Geyser for getting all streaming data in Rust directly from a running validator: https://docs.anza.xyz/validator/geyser
